# Values of Registers at Windows 10 Entry Point x64

Tags: windows, assembly, windows-10, x86-64, entry-point

I recently wrote a small program that simply displays a popup dialog box using the winapi. I started it in x64dbg debugger to see how it was compiled and learn a bit about assembly.

The first thing that I noticed was that the main thread does not start executing at the entry point of my code: it starts executing somewhere in `ntdll.dll`. This code seems to make several function calls before eventually calling `kernel32` which calls the entry point.

At the entry point, the registers have some values already loaded. I know they must be important as zeroing them in the debugger causes my program to crash. `rax` seems to be loaded with the entry point, but I'm not sure what the values of the others do.

So what exactly does all of the code do before my entry point, and what values does it load into the registers?

Comment: The only defined register at entry is the stack pointer. All the others are implementation detail that are subject to change at any time.

Answer (score 4):

Windows process execution starts in the NT loader which is what's happening in the `ntdll.dll` / `kernel32.dll`. If you want details on all that, you should take a look at the [Windows Internals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/resources/windows-internals) books.

With Visual C++ programs the 'entry-point' for the process is `mainCRTstartup` which is inside the Visual C/C++ Runtime. It initializes the CRT, deals with global initialization, then dispatches to `main`, `wmain`, `WinMain`, etc.

The source for the CRT can be found in a Visual Studio installation: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\201?\<edition>\VC\ools\MSVC\<msvctoolset>\crt\src\vcruntime`. Note this function doesn't actually take any parameters.

There is only one x64 "ABI" defined called `__fastcall` and it's documented on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention). Per this definition: `RCX`, `RDX`, `R8`, and `R9` are the first four parameters of the function (unless it's a float/double which it isn't going to be for the entry-point). `RAX`, `RCX`, `RDX`, `R8`, `R9`, `R10`, `R11` are all volatile, with `RAX` being the return value. Because this function doesn't take any parameters, it doesn't care what the value is of any of those registers. Any *other* registers which are expected to be non-volatile will cause problems if it's zeroed--see [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-software-conventions?view=msvc-160#register-volatility-and-preservation) for details.

> Visual C++ also has a `__vectorcall` but this is only used for internal SIMD procedure calls and is not used for cross-process or system calls. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/vectorcall)

Comment: Any guesses for the OP's observation that messing with register values on the call to `mainCRTstartup` leads to a crash?  Since it has no args, that can't be it. Perhaps changing call-preserved ("non-volatile") regs broke things for the eventual return to the caller?

Comment: @PeterCordes The original poster might've changed RSP or a segment register or something.